# Как программно задать путь для Path Animation в WPF?

Tags: wpf

```
Как программно задать путь для Path Animation в WPF? 
Например как связать Points c коллекцией из программного кода и менять ее?
    <PathGeometry x:Key="geometryPath">
        <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="10, 10">
            <PolyLineSegment Points="220,10 220,175 10,175" />
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
```

Answer (score 0):

обращаться к элементу из C#-кода по имени (атрибут `x:Name`), а не ключу (`x:Key`);
тогда для пустого(пока) элемента код XAML:

```
<PathGeometry x:Name="pathGeometry">
</PathGeometry>
```

а таким образом добавим твоё содержимое где-то в коде C#:

```
Point[] points = new Point[] { new Point(220, 10), new Point(220, 175), new Point(10, 175) };
PolyLineSegment pls = new PolyLineSegment(points, false);
PathFigure pf = new PathFigure();
pf.IsClosed = false;
pf.StartPoint = new Point(10, 10);
//pf.Segments.Clear();//!предварительная очистка, если надо только 1 единственный сегмент
pf.Segments.Add(pls);
//pathGeometry.Figures.Clear();//! ...если надо только 1 единственную фигуру
pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pf);
```